# Install DD4T templates for Tridion Web8

Tags: dd4t, web8

Can I use the same windows installer for Web8 or is there any other DD4T template installer has been provided.
DD4T.Templates 1.31 (windows installer) for Tridion 2009 / 2011 / 2013

https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/downloads/detail?name=DD4T-template-installer-1.31.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There currently are no official Web 8 compatible DD4T Templates, the latest DD4T 2.0 templates are available here: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases

There is a `install-templates.bat` file in the `DD4T.Templates.2.0.7.zip` that you can use to install these TBBs in your CMS. Using the 2013 version of the templates should work on Web 8 (just no support for Business Process Types for as far as DD4T would have a need for that).

You should also be able to use the 2013 templates from DD4T 1.31 on Web 8, since Web 8 is backwards compatible. That installer is nothing more than a fancy way to call the `TcmUploadAssembly.exe` like the batch file of the DD4T 2.0 templates is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded source code for DD4T Template 2.0.7, but not able to open the source code in VS2013 and show Targets error like this error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  D:\Projects\SDLWeb8\DD4TV1\DD4T.TridionTemplates.Targets Could you please suggest on this

Comment: @meyank you can best create a new question for that so the entire community can help you. But why download the sources, have you already tried to download the zip I mentioned and tried installing that as described?

Comment: yes i download the zip and install templates on sdl web8 now i want to setup DD4T site. could you please suggest on same how to move forward.