# Does DD4T version 1.31 support SDL Web 8?

Tags: dd4t, web8

Does DD4T 1.31 .NET Version supports SDL Web 8?
The similar question has been answered in the below post for Java Version. 
[DD4T versions for SDL Tridion 2013 and SDL Web 8?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/dd4t-versions-for-sdl-tridion-2013-and-sdl-web-8)

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the big question would be, why would you consider upgrading your CMS and still use an unmaintained framework for your web application?

DD4T 2.0 is the current and maintained release, there is full support in there for using the Web 8 CIL (https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.CIL).

However you should be able to use DD4T 1.31 with the Web 8 in process API, and even the CIL, since they are backwards compatible. There are no Web 8 providers built for DD4T 1.31, since it is not maintained anymore. But you can simply use the Web 8 Content Delivery stack by updating the assembly bindings in your `web.config` like I described in my article about using [DXA 1.2 with Web 8](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/23/dxa-1-2-and-web-8). Please note DXA is using the DD4T provider (be it the 2.0 version), hence the similarities, although you might need to do some additional steps for DD4T specificly.

Comment: Thank you Bart, While Migrating to Web 8 we have many applications which is running on  DD4T 1.31, As per client timelines we need to finish upgrade in less time, we thought of keep existing application as it is by upgrading provider and later move to DD4T 2.0. While in a discussion with SDL, We informed we are planning to use 2.0 they suggested to stick with 1.31 it self as DXA supports that. Appreciate your valuable feedback

Answer (score 0):

In the post marked by you, it is clearly mentioned.

For your scenario there are two options:

> 1. DD4T 1.31 will work with SDL Web 8 only you will have to compile with JDK 8.0
> 2. Upgrade to DD4T 2.* to get advantage of CIL / REST from Web 8.

**Update based on additional Input:**

Yes, DD4T 1.31 is supported for Web 8 for .Net, please refer to the question: [DD4T for Web8](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13653/install-dd4t-templates-for-tridion-web8)

Comment: What about DD4T 1.31 .NET version?

Comment: Please update your question to include that you are using .Net and not java as answered by other post.

Comment: Changed Thank you.

Comment: As per the update from other question that I I have updated in answer: DD4T 1.31 works with Web 8.

Comment: the given post mentioned dd4t templating, does dd4t delivery application supports web 8, do we have provider for web 8 in dd4t 1.3